# VS Code jump to a symbol but a cursor movement immediately brings focus back to original cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code

It was working OK. But today it becomes so, VS Code version is 1.63.2.

Scenario:

1. I press `Ctrl+Shift+O` to bring up the quick command palette to search for a symbol in current file.
2. I enter the symbol, the symbol is found and highlighted.
3. I press ENTER, focus jumps to the target position, cursor is also visible there.
4. As soon as I press a cursor movement key, e.g. `RIGHT`, or `h`, `j`, `k`, `l` keys as I use the `VSCodeVim` extension, cursor immediately goes back to the original position before the jumping to symbol action.

An animation:

- The initial position of the cursor is at line 1.
- Then I do a "jump-to-symbol", which brings the focus to line 530.
- But as long as I "move the cursor", it goes back to line 1.

[image: VSCode cursor not actually move to found symbol position]

Not sure which extension is the culprit. The following are my extensions:

```
> code --list-extensions
alefragnani.Bookmarks
azemoh.one-monokai
cschlosser.doxdocgen
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
eamodio.gitlens
GitHub.copilot
golang.go
jebbs.plantuml
jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax
llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd  
mark-wiemer.vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus
mjohns.clang-format
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers     
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit       
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
ms-vscode.powershell
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker  
twxs.cmake
vadimcn.vscode-lldb
vscodevim.vim
zero-plusplus.vscode-autohotkey-debug
```

Comment: You "may" be able to run the command `Help: Start Extension Bisect`  to help figure out whether one of the extensions is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to one of many navigation bugs in vscodevim. Recently this bug appear again with version 1.26.0

Downgrading to 1.25.2 fixes the issue

https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8595

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the autohotkey extensions? That or vim would fall in the scope of this bug. If disabling those doesn't work, post an issue in the GitHub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure, the issue is gone now, I literally was having this issue yesterday, then I even did not quit the VS Code, the issue is now just not happening... And I checked some extensions, seems there are no ones updated. Weird.